# How to Draw Boxplot With Outliers And Quartiles In Python

Tags: python, data-mining, boxplot

My Boxplot Shown Correctly But I Can't Understand Outliers And Quartiles..
My Boxplot Shown As Below
[image]

And This Is My Code

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'posts_dataset.csv')
df.boxplot(by='city', column=['price'], color='red')
plt.show()
```

How Can I Draw It As Other Formal Boxplots With Outliers And Rectangle Shape?

Comment: Adding a dataset might help you in getting better results..

Comment: @Pluviophile How to add dataset?

Comment: Upload in the cloud. Share the file link or add some samples in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your `price` has some huge outliers or it has a heavy tail, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':np.random.negative_binomial(0.1, 0.0001,5000),
                   'city':np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],5000)})
df.hist(column='price')
```

[image]

If you do a boxplot it will be squashed:

```
df.boxplot(by='city', column=['price'], color='red')
```

[image]

One option is to take the log10 :

```
df['log_price'] = np.log10(df['price']+1)
df.boxplot(by='city', column='log_price', color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks bro :) I think that works.just has a warning:RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10 .thanks again